# Simple abelian varieties of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ type with positive rank and large dimension

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$I would like know if there are known constructions of simple abelian varieties of $\GL_2$ type of arbitrarily large dimension and positive Mordell-Weil rank, whose rank is not forced to be positive by the functional equation. So either I want the associated modular form to have nontrivial character, or in the case it has trivial character I want sign of the functional equation to be $1$.

If I was not excluding the last part, then of course an obvious place to look would be among the new isogeny factors of $J_0(N)^+$, but I am explicitly excluding those.

Here some things I already tried/looked at:

Twisting elliptic curves (or other $\GL_2$-type abelian varieties of fixed dimension) by characters whose order get arbitrarily large might be one construction, but it seems to be difficult to prove that for large character order one can still get at least one with positive (analytic) rank among these twists. Even if one varies over all abelian varieties of a fixed dimension.

I also know of the construction using Jacobians of curves in a MathOverflow question on the [Mordell-Weil rank of abelian varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292426/mordell-weil-rank-of-abelian-varieties) but that doesn't seem to produce abelian varieties of $\GL_2$-type in general. Is there maybe some tweak of that construction that does produce $\GL_2$-type abelian varieties of arbitrarily large dimension?

LMFDB seems to have [some examples of dimension up to 5](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/?hst=List&weight=2&dim=4-&char_order=1&analytic_rank=2%2C4%2C6%2C8%2C10%2C12&search_type=List) with trivial character that have sign 1 in their functional equation (i.e. even analytic rank $> 0$), here I am assuming BSD. It also has [some examples of dimension up to 10](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/?hst=List&weight=2&dim=8-&char_order=2-&analytic_rank=1-&search_type=List) with non trivial character (these all have analytic rank 1 so BSD is known).

Andrew Sutherland kindly helped with some massive computations to extend the search for $\GL_2$-type abelian varieties with non trivial character whose conductor is prime, and found that the dimension was always $\leq 8$, for the prime conductors $< 100,000$. And in fact the dimensions seemed to get smaller rather then larger since dimension $> 4$ only occurred for primes $< 10,000$.

So except for arbitrarily large dimension I would also be interested in examples of dimension $> 8$.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but there are analytical methods to prove large rank: in the $\Gamma_0(N)$ case and sign $-1$ this was done here http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_2000__128_2_219_0 I don't know if this could be extended to nontrivial character.

Comment: Hi @FrançoisBrunault, Thanks for your comment. But the construction there is exactly the one I wanted to exclude, since they use sign -1 of the functional equation. That approach will as far as I understand not work in cases where the sign is either 1, or the character is nontrivial. The key part of my question is if one can at least still do something in these other cases. Although it is still good to have a reference that gives an explicit lower bound on the dimension in the case that I was excluding.

Comment: I think probably this is unknown.  It makes sense that positive rank together with positive sign gets rarer as the degree grows, since not only the associated modular form but all its Galois conjugates would have to fail to have the minimum analytic rank, which is supposed to be rare for a single modular form - it's like a chain of coincidences.

Comment: @M.D. I was thinking of using Heegner points / Euler systems for $X_1(N)$ instead of $X_0(N)$ but I am not expert. My (small) experience is that $L(f,\chi,1)$ is "usually" non-zero but I don't know how to quantify that.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault thanks, maybe I was judging your comment to quickly. Yes, indeed with $X_1(N)$ we do still have analytic rank 0 or 1 implies algebraic rank 0 or 1 (although the construction of the point in the rank 1 case comes from Kato using K-theory and not Heegner points if I remember correctly). Since in this case $L(f,\chi,1)$ being zero is already rare, it would be even more surprising if it often had double zero's. So indeed in this case having some sort of idea whether $L(f,\chi,1)$ can vanish for arbitrarily large characters will give an answer to what to expect.

Comment: However being more an Algebraïc person then an analytic one I do not see how to force zero's of these L functions if the functional equation does not help you...